# Placing an array in a WHERE statement - MySQLdb, Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a variable called bizIds which are assigned to an array based on a previous query:

```
bizIds = data[i]
```

I am trying to insert data in my database where a specific business ID is in the table.

This is my code so far:

```
        bizIds = data[i]
        #do some stuff

        cursor = db.cursor()                

        ##Inserting into Datebase
        writeIt = """INSERT INTO business (`Industry`,`Company Form`) VALUES (%s, %s) WHERE `Business ID` = %s""" 

        ##Executing the query
        cursor.execute(writeIt, (Industry.text, CompanyForm.text, bizIds))
        db.commit()
```

When I run the program, I get the error message: `(1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'WHERE Business ID = ("\'0986132\'",)\' at line 1')` So it shows the correct business ID in the parenthesis, but it doesn't insert the record.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what Industry.text and CompanyForm.text are, but I assume they are coming from some other part of your script.

I think you need to use UPDATE instead of INSERT INTO.

```
writeIt = """UPDATE business SET `Industry` = %s, `Company Form` = %s WHERE `Business ID` = %s"""
```

INSERT INTO adds records, and does not support the WHERE clause. This is the source of your original error. You seem to want to update records that already exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's what I get for being tired and trying to code! I have one more question for you. I replaced the INSERT with UPDATE, as you suggested, but now I'm getting this error: `(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")` I think it has to do with the `cursor.execute` line. I'm going to research it more. Any thoughts/opinions?

Comment: One more thing, when I print the bizIds for that loop, I noticed that the output was like this `('0986132',)` could that be the problem?

Comment: I fixed it! Thank you!